# Почему readline читает строку через одну?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Users\Downloads\dataset_3380_5.txt', 'r') as url:
  for file in url:
    file = url.readline().strip().split()
    print(file)
```

Выводит:

```
8 Andrews 166

10 Bishop 175

3 Paterson 136

10 Higgins 167

4 Brown 145
```

Должен вывести:

```
6 Andrews 155
8 Andrews 166
5 Porter 147
10 Bishop 175
2 Larkins 129
3 Paterson 136
6 Parkinson 159
10 Higgins 167
8 Farmer 165
4 Brown 145
11 Carey 174
```

Comment: `for file in url:` - зачитывает первую строку в переменную 'file'. И тут же `file = url.readline()` зачитывает в ту же переменную вторую строчку, которую вы и выводите. Ну так далее, вы читаете по 2 строчки за раз и первую игнорируете.

Answer (score 3):

Объект типа `file` в Python сам по себе является итерируемым объектом. Поэтому
в следующей строке кода вы уже итерируетесь по строкам файла:

```
for file in url:
```

и когда вы дополнительно делаете `url.readline()` вы уже читаете следующую строку файла - 2ю, 4ю, 6ю, и т.д.

Поэтому правильно будет переписать ваш код так:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Users\Downloads\dataset_3380_5.txt', 'r') as url:
  for line in url:
    cols = line.strip().split()
    print(cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так.

```py
with open(r'C:\Users\Users\Downloads\dataset_3380_5.txt', 'r') as file:
    for row in file.readlines():
        output = row.strip().split()
        print(output)
```

P.S. В след раз используйте вставку кода, что бы ваш вопрос проще было читать.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Самый легкий способ это изменить функции print.

```
print(text,end = "")
```

end пишется если надо изменить конец строки. Если не написать эту функцию то после print будет написан после текста перевод на новую строку